# How to consume external API with server side in ReactJs in one project?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to consume an API of a company, and this API could not be consumed with a **Client Side** Script such as Javascript, I want to use **react js** to consume this API on the **Server Side** but on the same project.

I asked the owner of the API and I receive an email :
***It is not possible to use our API request in a client-side language script such as Javascript, it must be used in a server-side script.***

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your question doesn't entirely make sense. Do you mean you want your React client app to make a request to your server, which then makes a request to the external API on the client's behalf and returns the result? If so, what *is* your server, and what attempt have you made to implement this?

Comment: No. I want use an API of a weather company, they told me in email that our API counld not be consuming with a client side script, and I must use a server side to consome the API, But for me, I want to do that in React Application

Comment: You *said* no, but your description suggests you actually meant yes. If the API can't be consumed client side (e.g. because it requires credentials you don't want to make public) you'll have to do it server side.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to options:

1. create an API that works as a proxy and this API calls the other API (so, the proxy-api is called by client/react and the second API is just called by the proxy-api
2. use server side render in react (you can see more about this alternative in: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering)